# Finding called methods - reverse call hierarchy

Tags: java, static-analysis

Are there any tools that will, for a given method or class, list all methods that can be called by that method/class?

I am aware of code coverage tools, but I'm looking more for static analysis.

Obviously some kind of filtering system would be needed to stop the generated report being too big. I would want to identify all methods in the `com.mycompany.*` package hierarchy, for example.

I'm basically looking for an inverse version of the call hierarchy provided by IDEs like Eclipse and Idea.

Answer (score 1):

[bcel](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) and [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) permit to read and analyze class files. Then you can write the code which:

- look in the target  method all call ('invoke')
- look into constant pool components for their resolution

I don't have anything more friendly...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jarchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) tool, a static analysis tool that can help you to list all methods called by another method or a class.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can view the references to a method, class, or variable.

You can do this by right-clicking on the name of the object you're interested in, and selecting whichever scope applies to you:

```
References -> Workspace (Ctrl + Shift + G)
              Project
              Hierarchy
              Working Set...
```

or by typing: `Ctrl + Shift + G` to find references in your Workspace by default.